# Finding an explicit formula for a recursive sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

How to show that the recurrent formula

$$A_n=A_{n-1} + A_{n-2} +4.$$

gives a sequence of the form      $f(n)=cr^n+cr^n$?

The only way we are allowed to solve it, is with the quadratic formula $(r^2-r-1)$...

Comment: Mathematics is precise. Be formal and complete. What are the initial terms? What is the right hand side of your "quadratic formula" and what is its connection to this particular problem?

Comment: I want to get to that f(n)=c*r^n+c*r^n.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Consider $B_n = A_n+4$. Then $B_n=B_{n-1}+B_{n-2}$, which is a famous recurrence.

Comment: Actually, $A_n+2$ doesn't work. You want, as my more general answer shows, $A_n+4$.

Comment: @martycohen, oops, my bad. corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $B_n=A_n+4$, to get $B_n=B_{n-1}+B_{n-2}$.

Now you can solve the chactaristic equation $r^2-r-1$.

This gives $r=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, $r=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Therefore we have $$B_n= A \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+ B \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$$

Therefore

$$A_n= A \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+ B \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n -4$$

Where $A,B$ depend on your initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
suppose that
$a_n
=\sum_{i=1}^k c_i a_{n-k} + u
$.
To get rid of the
constant term,
so this will be a
homogeneous recurrence,
let
$a_i
=b_i-v
$.

Then
$b_n-v
=\sum_{i=1}^k c_i (b_{n-k}-v) + u
=\sum_{i=1}^k c_i b_{n-k}-v\sum_{i=1}^kc_i + u
$
or
$b_n
=\sum_{i=1}^k c_i b_{n-k}-v(-1+\sum_{i=1}^kc_i) + u
$

Therefore,
if we choose
$v = \dfrac{u}{-1+\sum_{i=1}^kc_i }
$,
this is what we want.

Of course this assumes that
$\sum_{i=1}^kc_i 
\ne 1
$.
If
$\sum_{i=1}^kc_i 
= 1
$,
we have to do something else.